# Jquery Select ul of two different classes

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12360312/new_nav.html

I have one multi-level Nav bar. Right now everything is done through CSS.

I want the drop-downs to happen through JQuery on tapping or clicking them.

I am using JQuery toggle function like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

That makes the 1st level Drop down work with JQuery. Now how shall I make the same happen to 2nd level dropdown?

I am a newbie in JQuery. So what I have written... is that correct technically?

Please see the source code of the link to know my CSS and HTML :)

Thank you

Here is the HTML and CSS

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: left;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
}
ul li ul.dropdown{
    min-width: 125px; 
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block;
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
    display: block;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

ul li ul li ul.dropdown2 {
    left: 125px;
    top:0;
    display: none;
}
ul li ul li:hover ul.dropdown2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 124px;
    top:0;
    display:block;
}  
</style>


</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Laptops &#9662;</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown2">
                            <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sony</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post  your HTML. Your JavaScript is worthless without the content of the actual page.

Comment: Posting HTML will take a big place. Thats why I put the link and mentioned clearly to view its source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $("li").click(function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // to stop the event to propagating to the parent ul's and closing/opening unwanted dropdowns
        $(event.target).parents('li').eq(0).find(">ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOXQvK

Comment: Thank you Nojan. I replaced my code with yours but that stopped even the 1st level dropdown. And how with your code the 2nd level dropdown will work. It doesn't targets the .dropdown2 class.

Comment: @InfiniteMystery Could you please share a JSFiddle or Codepen of your code?

Comment: @InfiniteMystery This should be what you're looking for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOXQvK made some changes to the JS & CSS

Comment: Thank you Dear Nojan. It works perfect but I dont understand your code. I was trying to learn. This code I don't understand $(event.target).parents('li').eq(0).find(">ul").toggle();

Comment: @InfiniteMystery No problem. This line simply means get the element that click event fired on (this could be the anchor tag inside the `li` or any other element) and then find the first ( `.eq(0)` ) parent `li` and then find the first immediate `ul` child and `.toggle` it.